# CS6: transparent border when resizing image

Tags: cs6

this seems to be a CS6 bug to me - i couldn't find any solution yet:
when resizing an image, i'm getting a half-transparent 1px border around it. very annoying :(
i already tried flattening before resizing - still the same problem.
any idea how to avoid this? thanks

Comment: Just wanted to add to Joonas' answer that the *reason* for this is related to the interpolation while resizing. Sometimes the data is interpolated against data which doesn't exist and will result in this. Turning off interpolation will remove this, but of course, in most cases this is unwanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior has been around for ages.

Only solution that I know of, is to change the image layer into a `Background` layer before resizing.

From the top menu: `Layer > New > Layer from background`

---

---

Flattening also merges everything into one `Background` layer. It might be better for some situations.

From the top menu: `Layer > Flatten image`